# Laravel .htaccess problem

Tags: apache2, .htaccess, laravel

Trying to configure my website on the hosting according to SEO requirements (www exclusion and https) getting cycling redirect as a result. Can't figure out what's wrong.

Hosting has Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-133-generic x86_64) installed.

I've removed .htaccess from "public" directory and here is my .htaccess file in the root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ public/%1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Added description as you've asked

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have error in RewriteRule

try to replace

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ public/%1 [L,R=301]
```

by

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]
```